# Python subprocess package not installing

Tags: python

Errors in packages in Python: I am trying to use the `subprocess` and `check_output` in Python. I run the following:

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
from subprocess import check_output

print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

I try the following in Jupyter notebook and get the following error.

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-96ca67a4cf87> in <module>()
      2 import pandas as pd
      3 from subprocess import check_output
----> 4 print(check_output(["ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    334 
    335     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 336                **kwargs).stdout
    337 
    338 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    401         kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
    402 
--> 403     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    404         try:
    405             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    707                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:
    711             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    995                                          env,
    996                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
--> 997                                          startupinfo)
    998             finally:
    999                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

With this error I asume the `subprocess` is not installed so i run `!pip install subprocess` and get this message..

```
Collecting subprocess
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement subprocess (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for subprocess
```

I am new to Python.

EDIT: I now get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-d1bde9bd8aa2> in <module>()
----> 1 print(check_output(["/bin/ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    334 
    335     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 336                **kwargs).stdout
    337 
    338 

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    401         kwargs['stdin'] = PIPE
    402 
--> 403     with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
    404         try:
    405             stdout, stderr = process.communicate(input, timeout=timeout)

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, encoding, errors)
    707                                 c2pread, c2pwrite,
    708                                 errread, errwrite,
--> 709                                 restore_signals, start_new_session)
    710         except:
    711             # Cleanup if the child failed starting.

~\Anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py in _execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_start_new_session)
    995                                          env,
    996                                          os.fspath(cwd) if cwd is not None else None,
--> 997                                          startupinfo)
    998             finally:
    999                 # Child is launched. Close the parent's copy of those pipe

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado
```

Comment: `subprocess` module does not require installation, it's a part of standard library. You don't have `ls` program installed on Windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `subprocess` module is a part of the standard library in Python. The problem is probably that it cannot find the `ls` command.

Your code should be

```
print(check_output(["/bin/ls", "../input"]).decode("utf8"))
```

Or wherever you happen to have `ls` installed

Comment: I just tried what you suggested and I get another error (I put in the original comment)